# Javascript Event Handler Image Object

Tags: javascript, html

I need help understand the following javascript. How is it that the the image is being drawn on the context before the source is being set on the image? I'm reading an HTML 5 game development book and this is sample book from the book.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(img,100,100);
}
img.src = 'images/sprites.png';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is not being drawn before the `src` is set on the image. The image is being drawn inside the `img.onload` event handler function which is called only once the image loads:

```
image.onload = function () {
    context.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
};
```

In plain English this reads as *"draw the image only once it loads."*

What's happening here?

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  // get the 2d context

var image = new Image;                  // create a new image object

image.onload = function () {            // once the image loads
    context.drawImage(image, 100, 100); // draw the image
};

image.src = "images/sprites.png";       // load the image
```

You may define the `onload` function either before or after setting `image.src`. It doesn't really matter. However most people like to define it before.

Answer (score 0):

if you see its img.onload which means the function works once the image is loaded on page. so the source is set first and than the image is drawn.